# Can't set Location Controls in Android Device Monitor

Tags: android, gps, android-emulator, android-device-monitor

I want to be able to set the GPS coords for my emulator, but in Android Device Monitor the option to set them is greyed out for me (see below). The emulator used for the screenshot below is a Nexus_S_API_23, but I've tried with a few other emulated devices and still have the same issue.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set GPS coordinates to try out in your app, you can just run the app in your emulator and press Ctrl + Shift + L or click the three dots (...) in the emulator panel and navigate to the "Location" tab inside the "Extended controls" window that pops up.

You can find more detail under https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html at "Working with the Extended Controls, Settings, and Help".

Hope that helps.